# Why does this subscription block the main thread?

Tags: ruby, reactive

I am trying to play with RxRuby, and would like to turn data received from a tcp socket into a stream that can be consumed.  The following code "works" in that the data received from the socket is streamed, ie when new data arrives I get my "data = " messages,  but the subscription blocks.  If I add any code after the `subscription =` statement, it does not execute until I close the socket.  I would have expected to need a loop to keep the program from immediately completing.

```
require 'rx'
require 'socket'
Thread.abort_on_exception=true

class StellariumInterface
  attr_accessor :server, :client, :goto_stream

  def initialize(host:, port:)
    @host = host
    @port = port
    @server = TCPServer.new host, port
    @goto_stream = nil
    @client = nil
  end


  def accept
    puts "connecting"
    self.client = server.accept
    puts "connected"
  end

  def listen
    self.goto_stream = Rx::Observable.create do |observer|
      l = Thread.new do
        loop  do
          raw_data = client.recvfrom(1000)
          break if raw_data.first.empty?
          data = raw_data.first.unpack('ssqLl')
          p data
          observer.on_next(data)
          sleep 0.1
        end
        observer.on_completed
      end
    l.join
    end
  end



end

source = StellariumInterface.new host: 'localhost', port: 10001
source.accept
source.listen
subscription = source.goto_stream.subscribe(
  lambda { |x|  puts "data = #{x}" },
  lambda { |x|  puts "error "},
  lambda { puts "stream done "}
)
```

Comment: Does it still hang if you take out the .join?

Comment: I will check when I get home ... about an hour

Comment: @WedgeMartin,  that was it.  Feel free to post as an answer (maybe a little explaination would help as well)

Comment: Glad that helped! Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recvfrom` is a blocking operation, and even though it's inside of a new Thread, when the `join` takes place, it means the main thread is going to wait for the newly created thread.  If you remove the `join` it should allow the threads to remain independent and the looping thread will not block the main thread.